# iOS Firebase import warning & error

Tags: ios, swift, import, firebase, cocoapods

I always get the following warning by importing the Firebase Framework in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import Firebase -> File 'AppDelegate.swift' is part of module 'Firebase'; ignoring import
```

And the following error in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
FIRApp.configure() -> Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp'
```

I imported the Firebase Framework with CocoaPods.
That's my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Firebase' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Firebase
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Same problem here.Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AliHayder Not yet.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem might be that you have named your project `Firebase`

Comment: You're totally right , I had the same issue and I was naming my project like a Cocoapods framework

Answer (score 0):

You should uncomment second line "`# platform :ios, '9.0'`" in Podfile. I am pretty sure that is the problem there.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I uncommented the line and did a 'pod update' but it's still the same problem.